# EditText validation - no numbers

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I´m looking for an `android:inputType` for an EditText to make sure the user can´t enter any number, but all different kinds of lettres.
I thought, the [inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) is the right xml-attribute I have to change, but I can´t find a suitable value. Does anybody have a solution? Does `android:digits` help?

Thanks in advance,
Jonathan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) to restrict the input in a way that isn't available in `inputType`.  I think `android:digits` is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Great! This really works fine. Now I understood how `android:digits`, `android:inputType` and `InputFilters` are used. Thank you